Отсутствует make Linux Ubuntu
Пытался установить дополнительную версию python по документации.
Загрузил source code, распаковал и перешел в полученную папку.
Хочу ввести
./configure
make
make install

Но получаю
user@user-MCLF-XX:~/Downloads/Python-3.8.20$ make
Command 'make' not found, did you mean:
  command 'bake' from snap bake (0.1.3)
  command 'cmake' from snap cmake (3.30.4)
  command 'mace' from snap mace (0.2.0)
  command 'mame' from snap mame (mame0269)
  command 'rake' from snap ruby (3.3.5)
  command 'umake' from snap ubuntu-make (master)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.

Пытался
user@user-MCLF-XX:~/Downloads/Python-3.8.20$ sudo apt install make
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate

И
user@user-MCLF-XX:~/Downloads/Python-3.8.20$ sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate


Что я делаю не так?

а что это за убунта и что вы с ней делали? ) очень странная проблема, видимо кто-то убрал дефолтные репозитории пакетов из sources.list. Можете показать /etc/sources.list?

sudo apt update делали же?

Установить пакет build-essential. Посмотреть в документации возможно нужны ещё какие-нибудь пакеты.

Но вообще идея ставить собирать питон из исходников очень-очень странная. Наверняка есть другой путь

Гугл говорит что есть pyenv https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
